# How to convert latin character into HTML Entity (Decimal) in c#?

Tags: c#

i want to convert latin character into html entity code in c#

for example 
Th‚rŠse Ramdally should convert into

Th&#8218;r&#352;se Ramdally

Thanks 
vela

Comment: Technically note that the `A` letter is really called [**LATIN** CAPITAL LETTER A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0041/index.htm) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution is to encode every character that's beyond ASCII character table (i.e. character >= 128 or character < 32):

```
  String source = @"Th‚rŠse Ramdally";

  String result = String.Concat(source
    .Select(c => (c < 128 && c > 31) 
                    ? c.ToString() 
                    : String.Format("&#{0};", (int) c)));
```

Comment: I was just going to say to you to exclude codes < 32 :-)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry thats worked like a charm :) thanks a lot